# What do these things in the popup when I enable clustering in Galaxybase mean?

Tags: graph-databases

What do the "Initial Memory", "Maximum Memory", "Graph Data Cache" and "External Unique Identifier Cache" in the popup window when I enable clustering mean? What's the difference?
What is the role of "graph data cache"? How big ist the default size when deploying, and how to change the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galaxybase requires memory configuration at startup.
There are three main parts: computational memory, graph database cache, and external unique identifier cache.

The "initial memory" and "maximum memory" settings in the pop-up window here are computational memory, which is mainly used for graph queries and graph algorithms, and are recommended to be set to the same value.

The "graph data cache" is mainly used for temporary caching of graph data, which has a certain impact on the query efficiency.For example, when performing add, delete and change operations on the data, the data is first put into this cache, and then if a query operation is performed, it is possible to find it in the cache. The default memory usage when we start is about 1/3 of the total memory of the node.This parameter is recommended for users to enlarge the memory when performing data loading or large-scale data addition, deletion and modification operations.

The "external unique identifier cache" is used to store the mapping between the external unique identifier (also called pk, external id) and the internal id of the vertex data. It determines the maximum number of vertexes that the graph database can hold. Generally 8G of this cache can hold 100 million vertexes.